# Routine works stand alone but not as part of larger sub routine

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine

This sub routine works

```
Sub aRefreshDataAndPivot()

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ThugLifeLIVE").Refresh

End Sub
```

and so does this one:

```
Sub t1()

Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshTable

End Sub
```

But when I put the two together, the data refreshes, but not the pivot.

```
Sub aRefreshDataAndPivot()

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ThugLifeLIVE").Refresh

Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshTable

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Worksheets("Pivot").Parent.Connections("ThugLifeLIVE").Refresh` instead - assuming refresh works otherwise.

Comment: no joy with that braX. But thanks. Yes, connection refresh works alright.

Comment: You might try a DoEvents between the two to make sure the connection refresh has time to respond.

Comment: thanks. Does not work either.

Comment: Make sure background refresh for your connection is set to false.

Comment: this fixes it! Any idea why background refresh on my connection prevents my pivot table being updated?